# How to simplify an expression, with a given term?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to simplify the following expression, simply replacing `(\[Omega]1 - \[Omega]2) == \[CapitalDelta]`:

```
1/2 + ((\[Omega]1 - \[Omega]2)^2 + 
  4 J12^2 \[Pi]^2 Cos[
    t Sqrt[4 J12^2 \[Pi]^2 + (\[Omega]1 - \[Omega]2)^2]])/(
 2 (4 J12^2 \[Pi]^2 + (\[Omega]1 - \[Omega]2)^2))
```

I am writing the following:

```
Simplify[1/
  2 + ((\[Omega]1 - \[Omega]2)^2 + 
   4 J12^2 \[Pi]^2 Cos[
     t Sqrt[4 J12^2 \[Pi]^2 + (\[Omega]1 - \[Omega]2)^2]])/(
  2 (4 J12^2 \[Pi]^2 + (\[Omega]1 - \[Omega]2)^2)), (\[Omega]1 - \
\[Omega]2) == \[CapitalDelta]]
```

but it does not even replace `(\[Omega]1 - \[Omega]2)` with `\[CapitalDelta]` and I am not sure why.

Comment: To make substitutions use [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) and make the LHS of the [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) as simple as possible. In this instance, `expr2 = expr /. \[Omega]1 -> \[CapitalDelta] + \[Omega]2`

Comment: `expr  /. \[Omega]1 - \[Omega]2 -> \[CapitalDelta]` works too.

Comment: You could also add a `TransformationFunction` to `Simplify`: `Simplify[eqn, 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, 
   Replace[\[Omega]1 - \[Omega]2 -> \[CapitalDelta]]}]`

Comment: In general, if `\[Omega]1 - \[Omega]2` didn't appear explicitly for pattern-matching in your equation, you could also attempt to `Eliminate` those two variables.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use `Simplify` for this. Just try the replacement:

```
1/2 + ((\[Omega]1 - \[Omega]2)^2 + 
     4 J12^2 \[Pi]^2 Cos[
       t Sqrt[4 J12^2 \[Pi]^2 + (\[Omega]1 - \[Omega]2)^2]])/(2 (4 \
J12^2 \[Pi]^2 + (\[Omega]1 - \[Omega]2)^2)) /. \[Omega]1 -> \
\[CapitalDelta] + \[Omega]2
```

with the following effect:

[image]

Have fun!